# How do I add a simple React.js component in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, reactjs, npm

Hi Amazing WordPress/React Community,

I've looked around the web and haven't really found a good answer for this. I want to add a "Widget" that is built with React.js to my wordpress site. It will not be dependent on any outside data. Besides adding npm modules and adding build processes to my gruntfile (to convert JSX to JS), what other steps do I need to take to show a very simple React Component like below:

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
      return {
         name: "Jake"
      }
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.name} </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Where would this Javascript file live in the typical WordPress file structure?

Thanks!!